# C++ console application not returning

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am running a C++ console application from the command line. The application queries data from a database system using ODBC and dumps the data into a text file. Occasionally, and especially when running few at the same time, the application doesn't return back leaving the command prompt waiting. I can't even stop it using ctrl-C. I have to use End-Task from Task Manager or ProcMon. I use fprintf at every step in the code and write to a separate log file, and I see that the application reached the end and supposedly called `return 0`. When it doesn't hang, the application takes about 40 seconds to query and dump the data. When the application hangs, I see that the log file and data dump files are generated as expected. 
I use ProcMon and I see that the thread is waiting for itself. I get this message:

> one or more threads of odbcsql.exe are in waiting status.

This is the stack trace that I find through ProcMon:

- ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2246
- ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x135e
- ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
- ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x373
- ntoskrnl.exe!KeStallWhileFrozen+0x1977
- ntoskrnl.exe!KeIsAttachedProcess+0x95d
- ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x152f
- ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
- ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x373
- ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xb2
- ntoskrnl.exe!setjmpex+0x34a3
- wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x598
- wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x3e4
- wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x23a
- wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x172
- ntdll.dll!LdrInitShimEngineDynamic+0x23d5
- ntdll.dll!memset+0xdd1e
- ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
- UMEngx86.dll+0x242f
- UMEngx86.dll+0x1ec5
- UMEngx86.dll!_RegQueryValueExW@24+0x1ba4
- UMEngx86.dll!_RegQueryValueExW@24+0x18b2
- UMEngx86.dll!_RegQueryValueExW@24+0x17f4
- ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x10e
- ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x88
- ntdll.dll!RtlReportSilentProcessExit+0x108
- ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x81
- odbcsql.exe+0x2f0c
- odbcsql.exe+0x3185
- ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x8f
- ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x5a

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: do you join all threads before exiting (returning from the main function)?

Comment: I don't explicitly use multi-threading inside my application. My code is 1000 lines, and the problem doesn't seem code specific because as I mentioned I see that all my code is being executed just fine (by looking at the log file).

Comment: Voting to close just because I didn't post some code is not fair of you. At least you could ask if I can post some code first (and I explained why not). The question doesn't need code. I am basically asking why would a C++ console application not exit the process even after reaching return 0.

Comment: 1000 lines of code you don't want to post here. Sadly we cant do a hell of a lot without it. After `return 0`, all of the variables on `main`'s stack will be destroyed followed by any global variables. One of the destructors is likely hanging. One suggestion is place a log message at the end of each of your destructors to see if it's one of yours.

Comment: ***Sadly we cant do a hell of a lot without it*** That is the problem.

Comment: ***I am basically asking why would a C++ console application not exit the process even after reaching return 0*** Looks like it is waiting on a synchronization object.

Comment: My code doesn't have any classes. It contains 2 structs, main method, and 5 other methods used throughout. Thanks all for trying.

Comment: `struct`s are `class`es. Sounds strange, but true. This is a bit simplistic, but picture a `struct` as being a `class` with `public:` on the first line of the body. Anyway, if it's not you it's most likely ODBC, with which I have too little familiarity to make intelligent suggestions. Have you tried attaching your development environment's debugger to one of the hung processes? You should be able to pause and get a stack trace with function names  to help you narrow down just who is blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue.

The hang was caused by the ODBC call `SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);`

Here's my original code that contains the issue:

```
if (hStmt != SQL_NULL_HSTMT)
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);

if (hDbc != SQL_NULL_HDBC) {
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
}

if (hEnv != SQL_NULL_HENV)
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
```

Since I'm disconnecting hDbc using `SQLDisconnect(hDbc);` then the call to `SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);` is causing the application to hang. The code execution continues and completes but the process hangs in waiting status.

After I removed `SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);` the process no longer hangs.